# How to make a tab delimited file based on many txt files?

Tags: r, function

The instructions are:

> Create a tab delimited file with all the abstracts. Each "field of the
> record should have each own column; Presenter, Title, …, Abstract. The
> Keywords should be split into individual keywords (separate columns),
> where you should take into account that there are at most 6 keywords.

One text file looks like this:
[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwVwA.png)

Here is what I wrote so far but I'm not sure if it is correct.

```
files_to_read <- list.files(path="Abstracts")
                            
creating_file <- function(abstracts) {
  require(stringr)
  lines <- readLines(con = abstracts)
 
} 

#creating_file("Abstracts")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more difficult task than you think. First, create a new project in RStudio. Then create a files directory in the project directory and collect all your files there.

After that, you can run the script below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(data.table)



readFile = function(fileName){
  lines = fread(text = fileName, sep = NULL, header = FALSE)
  
  tibble(txt = lines$V1[1:5]) %>% #1
    separate(txt, c("name", "value"), sep = ": ") %>% #2
    bind_rows(
      tibble(
        name = paste0("Keywords", 1:6),
        value = lines[6] %>% 
          str_match("(^.*): (.*)") %>% .[,3] %>% 
          str_split(", ", 6) %>% .[[1]] %>% .[1:6]) #3
    ) %>% #4
    bind_rows(
      tibble(
        name = "Abstract",
        value = paste(lines$V1[8:nrow(lines)], collapse = " ")) #5
    ) %>% #6
    pivot_wider(1:2) #7
}

files = dir_ls("files")
df = tibble()
for(file in files){
  df = df %>% bind_rows(readFile(file))
}
df

df %>% write_csv("Result.csv")
```

Since you are a beginner, let me explain step by step how it works.

There is a `file2.txt` in my `files` directory. Here is its content.

```
Presenter: Ronald Beginer 2
Title: Exploiting
Format: Lecture
Session: 2_mode
Date and time: 03-14-2009 8:30am
Keywords: Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA

An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
```

Now let me show you how my `readFile` function works when used to read this file.
First, I read the entire file into the variable `lines`

`lines = fread(text = fileName, sep = NULL, header = FALSE)`

And then I make it into `tibble`. Here are the next steps (see the comments).

**Step 1** output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  txt                             
  <chr>                           
1 Presenter: Ronald Beginer 2     
2 Title: Exploiting               
3 Format: Lecture                 
4 Session: 2_mode                 
5 Date and time: 03-14-2009 8:30am
```

**Step 2** output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  name          value            
  <chr>         <chr>            
1 Presenter     Ronald Beginer 2 
2 Title         Exploiting       
3 Format        Lecture          
4 Session       2_mode           
5 Date and time 03-14-2009 8:30am
```

Now watch out for step four we have to prepare a separate `tibble` with **exactly six keywords**. This `tibble` is made in step 3.

**Step 3** output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name      value                          
  <chr>     <chr>                          
1 Keywords1 Method                         
2 Keywords2 Two-Mode Data                  
3 Keywords3 QCA                            
4 Keywords4 Method                         
5 Keywords5 Two-Mode Data                  
6 Keywords6 QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA
```

**Step 4** output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   name          value                          
   <chr>         <chr>                          
 1 Presenter     Ronald Beginer 2               
 2 Title         Exploiting                     
 3 Format        Lecture                        
 4 Session       2_mode                         
 5 Date and time 03-14-2009 8:30am              
 6 Keywords1     Method                         
 7 Keywords2     Two-Mode Data                  
 8 Keywords3     QCA                            
 9 Keywords4     Method                         
10 Keywords5     Two-Mode Data                  
11 Keywords6     QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA
```

Similarly, for step 6, we need to create a separate `tibble` that we attach to the rest. We create this `tibble` in step 5.

**Step 5** output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  name     value                                                                          
  <chr>    <chr>                                                                          
1 Abstract An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
```

**Step 6** output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   name          value                                                                          
   <chr>         <chr>                                                                          
 1 Presenter     Ronald Beginer 2                                                               
 2 Title         Exploiting                                                                     
 3 Format        Lecture                                                                        
 4 Session       2_mode                                                                         
 5 Date and time 03-14-2009 8:30am                                                              
 6 Keywords1     Method                                                                         
 7 Keywords2     Two-Mode Data                                                                  
 8 Keywords3     QCA                                                                            
 9 Keywords4     Method                                                                         
10 Keywords5     Two-Mode Data                                                                  
11 Keywords6     QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA                                                
12 Abstract      An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
```

In the last step, we'll make it wide.

**Step 7** output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 12
  Presenter        Title      Format  Session `Date and time`   Keywords1 Keywords2     Keywords3 Keywords4 Keywords5     Keywords6                       Abstract                       
  <chr>            <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>             <chr>     <chr>         <chr>     <chr>     <chr>         <chr>                           <chr>                          
1 Ronald Beginer 2 Exploiting Lecture 2_mode  03-14-2009 8:30am Method    Two-Mode Data QCA       Method    Two-Mode Data QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA An innovative ...bla bla bla a~
```

The rest is simple. Glue the thus obtained `tibble` for each file and save to one csv file.

**csv file**

```
Presenter,Title,Format,Session,Date and time,Keywords1,Keywords2,Keywords3,Keywords4,Keywords5,Keywords6,Abstract
Ronald Beginer 1,Exploiting,Lecture,2_mode,03-14-2009 8:30am,Method,Two-Mode Data,QCA,NA,NA,NA,An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
Ronald Beginer 2,Exploiting,Lecture,2_mode,03-14-2009 8:30am,Method,Two-Mode Data,QCA,Method,Two-Mode Data,"QCA, Method, Two-Mode Data, QCA",An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
Ronald Beginer 3,Exploiting,Lecture,2_mode,03-14-2009 8:30am,Method,Two-Mode Data,QCA,NA,NA,NA,An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other. An innovative ...bla bla bla and other.
```

P.S.
When writing questions on StackOverflow, **never put any data in the picture form!!**

Comment: Sorry for the picture, my mistake. But thank you so much for this answer and I really appreciate the explanation; i was looking for answers in a book i bought (Doing data science in R) but unfortunately there are no such complex problems... I will try this code today:)

Comment: Hello, I have a question with the step #1; I could't find what V1 stands for, if you could please tell me this:)

Comment: See what is `lines`. Usually a function `fread` not only read the lines of text file but also allocated to the respective fields. Unfortunately in your task you have another rule for the line 1:5, another rule for the line 6, and even one rule for the rest of the line. This is the reason for which forced I read the file to a table with variable `v1` without any pre-separation.

Comment: thank you!:) for all the help!

Comment: What grade did you get? Because it looks like homework to me. Well, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: It is a homework but i didn't submit it yet because I am still working on the part 2 of the homework:) This was just the first task.. I will let you know.